# ListView renders UserControl before bind

Tags: c#, xaml, mvvm, data-binding, uwp

In a nutshell, my problem is:

- I am rendering a collection of immutable items using a `ListView` (and `DataTemplate`) in a Windows Universal / UWP app.
- Since the items in the collection are immutable, I'd like to avoid change notification code and use the efficient `{x:Bind Mode=OneTime}` default.
- However, `MyUserControl` is rendered before its `UserControlViewModel` is bound. Debugging, I see a property `get` before `set`.

How can I ensure the `UserControlViewModel` is set before it renders `OneTime`?

---

A complete example follows:

**MainPage.xaml**

```
<Page x:Class="MyApp.MainPage" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" xmlns:local="using:MyApp" xmlns:sys="using:System">
    <ListView ItemsSource="{x:Bind PageViewModel}">
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate x:DataType="sys:String">
                <local:MyUserControl UserControlViewModel="{x:Bind}" />
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
</Page>
```

**MainPage.xaml.cs**

```
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls;
namespace MyApp {
    public sealed partial class MainPage : Page {
        public string[] PageViewModel { get; set; } = new string[] { "Item1", "Item2" };
        public MainPage() { InitializeComponent(); }
    }
}
```

**MyUserControl.xaml**

```
<UserControl x:Class="MyApp.MyUserControl" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
    <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind ViewModel}" />
</UserControl>
```

**MyUserControl.xaml.cs**

```
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls;
namespace MyApp {
    public sealed partial class MyUserControl : UserControl {
        public string UserControlViewModel { get; set; } = "Default Value";
        public MyUserControl() { InitializeComponent(); }
    }
}
```

This code renders a page with two lines containing the text "Default Value"; instead my intent was to display the values "Item1" and "Item2".

---

If we make the `PageViewModel` an empty `ObservableCollection<string>` and populate it later, the problem is still present. Interestingly, replacing `ListView` with `ListBox`, or removing the `ListView` entirely, will `set` before `get`, and render as intended:

**MainPage.xaml**

```
<Page x:Class="MyApp.MainPage" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" xmlns:local="using:MyApp">
    <local:MyUserControl UserControlViewModel="{x:Bind PageViewModel[0]}" />
</Page>
```

Comment: Side note: You mentioned the collection is mutable, which in your code is a string array. Altering the content of the string array (=mutating it) will not trigger an update of the UI, since an (string) array has no facility to notify the binding mechanism. Instead of an array, choose a collection type with built-in change notifications (such as ObservableCollection<T>), which will enable you to mutate the collection while having the bound ItemsControl automatically update its view...

Comment: I don't know what precisely you mean with "_without the ListView container (i.e. a single item)?_". Thus, i am not sure whether i should be surprised or not ;-)

Comment: Actually, let me retract my first comment. I checked the documentation. `x:Bind` does not seem to have the requirement of the binding target needing to be a DependencyProperty (this seems to apply only to traditional bindings `{Binding ...}`). Sorry for the confusion :(

Comment: Hmm, the documentation (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/xaml-platform/x-bind-markup-extension#property-path) is somewhat lacking. It doesn't clearly spell out what the mode of operation is when your specify an x-bind without a path `{x:Bind}`. Being unable to test myself (no Windows 10 here), i can only guess the problem is related to not specifying a path with `{x:Bind}` in your template. What happens if you wrap your strings in a struct with a string property, use a array with those structs, and let the {x:Bind} in the template refer to the struct string property?

Comment: Alternatively to my suggestion in my last comment, what would happen if you use `{x:Bind Path=.}` or similar in your data template?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/183227/discussion-between-elgonzo-and-shannon).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With [some help from FEC-4RP at an MSDN forum](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/7028d30a-c171-4920-9c87-cb678f4fbad8/listview-renders-usercontrol-before-xbind), I'm starting to understand what is going on. By assigning each instance of `MyUserControl` a unique ID and rendering 100 of them in a `ListView`, I see that the controls are recycled by the framework. Therefore they obviously also need to support late binding.

That is, it seems ListView does render controls before binding them by design, and `OneTime` binding is not allowed in a UI Virtualizing panel. However, I'm not certain, since I haven't found this in documentation yet.

My suspicion is that the `VirtualizingStackPanel.VirtualizationMode` default changed to `Recycling` [in UWP](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.virtualizingstackpanel.virtualizationmodeproperty), from `Standard` [in .NET](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.virtualizingpanel.virtualizationmode?view=netframework-4.7.2).

Adding a DependencyProperty AND setting the default binding mode on `MyUserControl` (or all every binding that depends on the control's viewmodel, which is typically all of them) to something other than `OneTime` appear to be necessary.

Feel free to explain here more completely and I'll accept your answer, otherwise I'll complete this here with full information when I'm done.